# How to make firefox try to open a website before searching it

Tags: firefox, dns

I have set `.proj` as a superdomain for local development with custom CA for https.
Everything works fine except for one thing.

If i enter `application.proj` in the address bar, then instead of going to `https://application.proj` firefox is searching `application.proj` in google.

Is there a way to tell firefox to always try to DNS a website first before using google search?

Answer (score 1):

You can add your `proj` TLD to the `network.trr.builtin-excluded-domains` preference.

Open `about:config`, and search for "network.trr.builtin-excluded-domains". By default, it is set to "localhost,local".

Change it to "localhost,local,proj".

Or you can add it directly into your `prefs.js` file:

```
user_pref("network.trr.builtin-excluded-domains", "localhost,local,proj");
```

(Close Firefox before updating the file, since it overwrites it on exit)

Comment: Its not exactly the solution, firefox still directs me to google, but now it shows a `Did you mean to go to "http://testing.proj/"` button, that I can use to get to the website. Not perfect but a bit better.

Comment: @HubertNNN : Also, if you add a "/" at the end in the URL bar, it should work without asking you. Try `testing.proj/`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do that. If the `browser.fixup.dns_first_for_single_words` setting is enabled in `about:config` then firefox will use DNS only for known TLD and gTLDs (.com, .net, .org etc.). As `.proj` is not a known TLD, then firefox will not use DNS for that.